# How are a set of chi squared statistics distributed?

Tags: distributions, optimization, nonlinear-regression, differential-equations

I'm using a genetic algorithm to fit a system of ODE's to some data. Given the high dimentionality of the ODE model, the optimization problem is still a fairly difficult problem. Therefore I am performing multiple rounds of thousands of optimizations.

Here is an example of the sum of squares (SSR) values returned for 4000 parameter estimations.

[image]

Due to the high dimentionality and non-linearity of the system involved the parameter landscape has multiple local minima. This is evident from the graph above which shows that many parameter estimations have become stuck at higher SSR values and that the globl minima seems to be around 10e3. In order to analyse this data I want to remove parameter estimation runs that fall outside the global minimum. My question concerns the location of this cut-off point.

The method I'm considering to choose where I should draw the line between acceptable parameter estimation runs and not-acceptable is to 1) sort the estimation data in order of increasing chi squared values and then 2) fit a distribution n times to the data while sequentially removing the worst parameter estimation runs.

i.e. if n=4, I would fit 4 distributions.

```
k1    k2    SSR
3    4     1
5    4     2
2    7     4
7    9     6
```

Firstly with all data sets. Then remove one

```
k1    k2    SSR
3    4     1
5    4     2
2    7     4
```

and iterate. I then pick the best fit to the distribution of choice.

Since this method strongly depends on the distribution I choose to fit, my question is: how is a set of chi squared statistics generated in this way distributed around the global minimum?

[image]

Here is a close up of the global minimum for the data above. Can anyone suggest a statistical distribution that I could use for this purpose or indeed any other procedure that would accomplish the same thing?

My candidates are normal and chi squared (the obvious ones), but I have doubts as to whether the SSR values would be normally distributed about the best fit and comparing a chi squared distribution (below) with $p$ degrees of freedom (where $p=number of parameters$ and is 13 for this model) doesn't look that great.

[image]